# ¿Cómo leer mas/leer menos texto en una vista index.html.erb en cada registro del listado?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="bloque1" class="bloque1">
                        <%= "#{post.content[0..25]}... " %>
                        <button onclick="muestra2<%= "#{post.id}" %>();">leer mas</button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:none" id="bloque2" class="bloque2">
                        <%= post.content %>
                        <button onclick="muestra1<%= "#{post.id}" %>();">leer menos</button>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        function <%= "muestra1#{post.id}" %>(){
                            document.getElementById('bloque1').style.display="block";
                            document.getElementById('bloque2').style.display="none";
                        };
                        function <%= "muestra2#{post.id}" %>(){
                            document.getElementById('bloque1').style.display="none";
                            document.getElementById('bloque2').style.display="block";
                        };
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Mi objetivo es:

- Leer más texto o leer menos texto con los botones respectivos en cada registro del listado.

El problema que tengo es:

- Que sólo funciona para el primer registro del listado.

*¿Pueden ayudarme? Gracias!!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cada iteración del ciclo estás repitiendo ID's (bloque1 y bloque2) y estas deben ser únicas, precisamente, para evitar problemas como el que tienes. En vez de crear funciones "únicas" para cada elemento, crea ID única para cada elemento, solo dos funciones y envía ID como parámetro.

Los bloques quedarán así: `bloque1-###` y `bloque2-###`, donde `###` es ID de post `post.id`

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="bloque1-<%= "#{post.id}" %>" class="bloque1">
                        <%= "#{post.content[0..25]}... " %>
                        <button onclick="muestra2(<%= "#{post.id}" %>);">Leer más</button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:none" id="bloque2-<%= "#{post.id}" %>" class="bloque2">
                        <%= post.content %>
                        <button onclick="muestra1(<%= "#{post.id}" %>);">Leer menos</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function muestra1(postId){
    document.getElementById('bloque1-' + postId).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('bloque2-' + postId).style.display="none";
};
function muestra2(postId){
    document.getElementById('bloque1-' + postId).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('bloque2-' + postId).style.display="block";
};
</script>
```

Comment: Interpolar el id del post para volverlo string no es necesario. Con `<%= post.id %>` debería ser suficiente.

Comment: @AlterLagos, desconozco Ruby, así que solo adapté el código original. Pero hoy aprendí algo nuevo... ¡Gracias!